# Jquery - Is it possible to rename a js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope someone can help me.

I have a function like

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function my_test()
    {
     ... some code ... 
    }
</script>
```

Is it possoble to rename (or clone) this function to `my_test_2()` ?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Functions are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object) in Javascript. You can do:

```
var my_test_2 = my_test;
my_test_2();  // Calls the same function as my_test() does.
```

Comment: hm, strange. When i call my "clone function" i get this error "too much recursion"

Comment: @Peter, it seems the function ends up calling itself, leading to infinite recursion. Does `my_test()` contain a call to `my_test_2()` (or another alias)?

Comment: @Frédéric Hi, here is a little exmaple -> http://jsfiddle.net/v9ehJ/   ... Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @Peter, `my_test()` is declared twice, and `my_test_org` actually ends up referencing the second implementation because of [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting). You should use a function expression for the new `my_test()` instead of redeclaring it. I [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ehJ/1/) your fiddle accordingly.

Comment: i understand, thank you very much Frédéric! Greetz from Germany!

Comment: `function x(i) { if (i < 2) return x(i+1); else return i; };` then `var y = x; function x(){return 7;}` and `y(0) // => 7!!!` It does not rename.

Comment: @Ivan, that's hoisting. The first version of `x()` is never taken into account. Read more about it from the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_test_2 = my_test;
```

Functions are like variables, so my_test_2 will be a reference to the original.

Comment: Will it be a reference???
var x = function(){alert('hi!');} var y=x; x=function (){alert('hi2!');} And, y() still shows 'hi!', not 'hi2!'.